# Golang positive lookahead alternative

Tags: json, regex, go, expression

I need to add a password check pattern to the json schema that Golang handles.

```
"User" : {
        "type": "object",
        "required": ["password"],
        "properties": {
          },
          "password": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern":"^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[#%$!*+=_@-])[A-Za-z0-9#%$!*+=_-]{8,}$"               
          }
        }
```

- At least one digit  At least one lowercase character
- At least one uppercase character
- At least one special character
- At least 8 characters in length, but no more than 32.

The pattern doesn't work because Golang doesn't support positive lookahead

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[#%$!*+=_@-])[A-Za-z0-9#%$!*+=_-]{8,32}$
```

How to change the pattern to keep the password verification conditions and not use positive lookahead?

Comment: Identical to another one posted just 4 hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72932633/251311

Comment: Why should it be a _single_ regular expression? Why wouldn't you split it to 4?

Comment: How to split into 4 parts? I need to insert this expression in schema.json for password validation.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://groups.google.com/g/json-schema/c/8FQqL6P0UhI) can give some pointers?

Comment: @zerkms the positive and negative lookahead are supported and defined in the JSON schema specification.

Comment: @davidriod great, can go handle that?